# Getting rid of vertical viewbounce, but allow vertical scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a HTML5 app with Phonegap. I do use MS VisualStudio for the development. There is one really annoying thing. If I scroll over the top or under the bottom of my header/footer, there is this viewbounce effect MS uses. Don't get me wrong it might look nice somewhere, but my user navigates horizontally and thanks to that affect the app bounces up and down if he does not scroll perfectly horizontal.

I'm relying on jQuery Mobile for the standard layout. I can't disable the scrolling as one might suggest using `-ms-touch-action: none;` as the user has to scroll through a list, which is larger than the listview. Also I set `<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />` in Phonegaps config.xml, but I'm not totally sure if Visual Studio does respect the settings in the config.xml at all.

So in short: I want to get rif of the vertical bounce, while allowing vertical scrolling. Is there any way I'll be able to do that? Maybe by allowing the `-ms-touch-action` on specific elements, e.g. the list elements?

Cheers!

Comment: Is there an option for overscroll in the config file? If you disable overscrolling that might fix it

Comment: Hi, as far as I know, there is only the webviewbounce preference mentioned above. There might be others though which I don't know.

Comment: Ever find an answer to this? dealing with the same issue.

Comment: No - unfortunately not. I accepted my fate and integrated it. Whenever I did not need scroll I used ms-touch-action: none;